# Conditional expected value - $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$

Tags: probability

Let's assume that we have variable $X$ and $Y|X=x$ that are both discretely uniformly distributed:
$X \sim Ed\{1,2,....n\}$ and 
$Y|X = x \sim Ed\{1,2...x-1, x+1,..n\}$. ($Y|X\!=\!x$ doesn't have value $x$).
What is the expected value of $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)$?

My attempt: I know that $\Pr(y|x) = \dfrac{P(x=k,y=l)}{P(x = k)}$. From here on we can conclude that $\Pr(x=k,y=l) = \frac 1n\cdot \frac 1{n-1}$, for $k\neq l$ and zero otherwise.
So the question is what is the value of $\Pr(Y = l)$, since $\Pr(X|Y) = \Pr(x=k,y=l)/\Pr(y = l)$.

Comment: please use Latex

Comment: which function to use it? i'm new to this forum.

Comment: look up here for a starter: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: thanks a lot. i hope that the form is now o.k.

Answer (score 3):

By the law of total probability:
$$\Pr[Y=l]=\sum_{k=1}^n \Pr[Y=l | X=k]\cdot \Pr [X=k]=\sum_{k=1}^n \cdot \frac{\mathbb{1}_{k\neq l}(k)}{n-1}\cdot\frac1n=\frac{n-1}{n-1}\cdot\frac 1n=\frac 1n$$

Answer (score 2):

I have a longer analytical solution, but I think this argument via symmetry is more elegant:

We know that $X$ is marginally uniformly distributed over the points $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Now, we also know that if $X=i$, then $Y$ **cannot** take the value $i$. Hence, if $Y=j$ is observed, then $X$ **cannot** have taken the value $j$. So what values could $X$ have taken?

Well, by symmetry, $X$ must then be uniformly distributed over the $n-1$ points $\{1,\ldots,j-1,j+1,\ldots,n\}$. Hence $P(X=i|Y=j)=\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Finally, 
$$
E(X|Y=j)=\sum\limits_{i\ne y=1}^n iP(X=i|Y=j) = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i\ne y=1}^n i=\frac{1}{n-1}(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-j)
$$

Comment: Very nice argument!

Comment: Would we still use the law of total probability in this case:$X \sim Ed\{1,2,....n\}$ and 
$Y|X = x \sim Ed\{1,2...x\}$

Comment: YOur reasoning is sound, but the uniform (with a hole) probabilty does not lead to that expectation.

Comment: leonbloy is right: the expectation is not the one you wrote (I think you  intended to write the probability)

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=j] = (n(n+1)/2-j)/(n-1)$

Comment: @user160522: I apologise for the earlier comment. Yes you do use it in the final step to calculate the expectation. I have modified the solution above.